# django check admin inline values

Tags: django

i have the following condition:

1. model A
2. model B that have a foreign key of type A and an integer field that can be

blank.

in the admin page i have model B as inline of model A and i can add many of them

at a time.

i need to check that if one of the B objects that point to the same A object

have the integer field not empty then all of the B objects that points to the

A object have their integer as not empty.

is there a way for me to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the formset used by inline for your B model, you can override a `clean()` method on it:

```
class InlineModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    ...
    formset = MyInlineFormSet
    ...
```

and

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super(MyInlineFormSet, self).clean()

        # Your custom validation. You can access all the forms via `self.forms`
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.formset) and code:

- [`BaseFormSet.clean()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L360)
- [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1737)